# Save or store data in a database from program

Tags: php, mysql, database, store

I am writing a Code where the user has to register to perform some exercises. Each exercise has an `'id'` and the user can choose what level of difficulty the exercise has.

I would like to save the `'exercise_id'`, `'user_id'` and `'difficulty'` in a table of a database. So far I have managed to save in a table called `'answers'` the `'exercise_id'` and `'difficulty'`, but I cannot save the `'user_id'`.

Before choosing the exercise and the level of difficulty, the user must register with their username, and every time one registers, the `'user_id'` is created and increasing (I have managed to save this in the `'users'` table). What I would like to do is save the `'user_id'` that is currently logged in the table `'answers'`.
This is what I have so far ... Could you help me?

Im trying to Fetch the '`user_id`' that is logged from the table '`users`' and store it in the table '`answers`' when the user press `submit`

This is the file: ChooseExercise.php

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "project";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
/*echo*/ $id=$_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM exercises where exercise_id='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql); /*Check connection*/
?>

<div id="centered_B" class="header">

<?php
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo '<h1>' . $row["exercise_id"]. ". " . $row["title"] . '</h1>' . "<br>" . '<p>' . $row["text"] . '</p> <img width="603" height="auto" src="' . $row["image_path"] . '"><br><br>


    <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "1" /><img src="' . $row["image_path_A"] . '"/><br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "2" /><img src="' . $row["image_path_B"] . '"><br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "3" /><img src="' . $row["image_path_C"] . '"><br>';


/*var_dump($id)*/
?>

    <br><br><br><!--- Select difficulty --->

    <p2>Select difficulty level:</p2>

    <form action='' method='post'>
    <select name="choose" id="choose">>
        <option value="1" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="1") { echo "selected"; } ?> >1</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="2") { echo "selected"; } ?> >2</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="3") { echo "selected"; } ?> >3</option>
        <option value="4" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="4") { echo "selected"; } ?> >4</option>
        <option value="5" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="5") { echo "selected"; } ?> >5</option>
    </select>

    <br><br><br><!--- Button --->

<!--        <button class="buttonSubmit" >Submit</button>-->
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        <button class="buttonNext" >Next Question</button>
    </form>

</div><!--- end of centered_B div --->



<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']; /*ERROR: Notice: Undefined index: user_id */
   $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$user_id'";


    if(isset($_POST['choose'])){
        $difficulty=$_POST['choose'];
//      */$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];*/
        $query = "INSERT INTO answers (exercise_id_fk, student_id, difficulty_student) VALUES ('$id','$user_id', '$difficulty')";
        $sql=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    }
}

?>

<div id="centered_C" class="header">
    <!--- Solution --->

        <button onclick="solutionFunction()" class="button_Solution" >Solution</button>



    <div id="solution" style="display: none;">

        <img src="<?php echo $row["solution_path"]; ?>" >

    </div>


</div><!--- end of centered_C div --->

<!--------- Solution -------------->
<script>
    function solutionFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("solution");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is the file: server.php

```
<!--Mysql DataBase-->

<?php
session_start();

// initializing variables
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array();

/*Connect with the DB*/
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "project";

$db = new mysqli($servername, "root", $password, $dbname);


// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
    // receive all input values from the form
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
    $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

    // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled ...
    // by adding (array_push()) corresponding error unto $errors array
    if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
    if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
    if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }
    if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
        array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
    }

    // first check the database to make sure
    // a user does not already exist with the same username and/or email
    $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($user) { // if user exists
        if ($user['username'] === $username) {
            array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
        }

        if ($user['email'] === $email) {
            array_push($errors, "email already exists");
        }
    }

    // Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database

        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) 
              VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
        mysqli_query($db, $query);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['user_id'] = mysqli_insert_id($db);
var_dump(mysqli_insert_id($db));
        header('location: index.php');
    }
}

// ...
// check if the user has filled the form correctly

// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

    if (empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = MD5($password); /*security reasons*/
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results->fetch_object()->id; //returns id from last query /*StackO*/
            header('location: index.php');
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }
    }
var_dump($results->fetch_object()->id);
}

?>
```

DATABASE TABLES

```
CREATE TABLE answers(
    exercise_id_fk INT,
    student_id INT,
    difficulty_student INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(exercise_id_fk) REFERENCES exercises(exercise_id)
);


CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: For updated question

Before `header('location: index.php');` on both register and login:

1) On **REGISTER USER**, save the user id in SESSION:

```
// Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
if (count($errors) == 0) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES('$username')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = mysqli_insert_id($db); //returns id from last query

    header('location: index.php');
}
```

}

2) On **LOGIN USER**, do the same, but retrieving from the database:

```
if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = MD5($password); /*security reasons*/
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results->fetch_object()->id;
        header('location: index.php');
    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
    }
}
```

Comment: Okey, I did as you told me but I have the following error: Error suppression ignored for. What do you think it is?

Comment: Im also storing data in the Tables in 2 different php files, do you think is because of that?

Comment: @ana Error suppression ignored for? For what? Is this the complete error?

Comment: Sorry, the error is: SCREAM: `Error suppression ignored for Notice: Undefined variable: user_id` and `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION`

Comment: @ana And where exactly is this occurring? Probably on your `var_dump($user_id)` since it was never defined in the first place.

Comment: Maybe I have this error because I'm storing the `user_id` in the Table in another php file?

Comment: Also, you should have `session_start()` in the beginning of your script or `$_SESSION` will not work.

Comment: I put `session_start()` before connecting  to the database but I still have this error: `Notice: Undefined variable: user_id`. Should I put `session_start()` in every php file I have?

Comment: You don't use `session_start()` because you want to connect to the database. You use it because you want to access PHP session variables. So you must include `session_start()` on every .php file that needs session variables. Try including it on both .php files you have.

Comment: Okey I did as you told me and I only have one error. I'll post it below where is my error as an answer but I can delete it later as its not a correct answer for my question.

Comment: I'd much prefer if you would edit your original post with every file you're using in your project with the full code in each, would be a lot easier to provide meaningful help.

Comment: I have a lot of php files... Is this enough information for you tu help me? Or how can i show you my files?

Comment: The 2 php files you're using, one for submitting the form and the other to interpret the submission

Comment: I'm showing you my 2 php files above. I have more files but I think these are the important ones for what I need. Let me know if you need to see more code.

Comment: Yes! These are great, I'm taking a look at them. Would you mind updating your original question with these 2 files (they're not long at all) and delete your own answer? To keep things tidy.

Comment: Sure! I'll change my original question and post the files I showed you below.

Comment: @ana I have updated my answer according to the new update on the question. Also, just to be sure, you are indeed doing either register or login before accessing ChooseExercise.php correct? As in, you're not accessing ChooseExercise.php directly without first login or register, just to confirm.

Comment: Thanks @AmmoPT, I'll change the code and see if it works and I'll let you know. Yes! I have a register.php and login.php file before accesing ChooseExercise.php. I'm not accessing directly to ChooseExercise.php.

Comment: I changed the code as you told me but I have an error here in the file ChooseExercise.php:  `$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']; /*ERROR: Notice: Undefined index: user_id */`

Comment: Can you add `var_dump(mysqli_insert_id($db))` on register and `var_dump($results->fetch_object()->id)` on login to make sure that in both places the id is returned?

Comment: Hey! It's working now!! Thank you so much for your time Ammo!